# Post url is not coming in anchor href tag

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

My code is

```
$args=array(
'post_type' => "product",
'post_status' => 'publish',
'taxonomy'   => 'products_category',
'order' =>'ASC',
'number'     => '',
'hide_empty'  => 0 );
 $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<ul class="product_category">';
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href='. the_permalink() .'>';
            echo the_title();
            echo '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
    }
 echo '</ul>';wp_reset_query();
```

I want to show posts of product post type. Posts are coming correctly, but link of post not coming inside a href tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the_permalink() use get_permalink();

```
$args=array(
'post_type' => "product",
'post_status' => 'publish',
'taxonomy'   => 'products_category',
'order' =>'ASC',
'number'     => '',
'hide_empty'  => 0 );
 $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<ul class="product_category">';
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href='. get_permalink() .'>';
            the_title();
            echo '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
    }
 echo '</ul>';wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `get_permalink()`  instead of `the_permalink()`, if still problem persist try `$my_query->get_permalink()`